# What are all these errors about?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, smart-pointers, stdmap

I hate copypasting the whole log here but I can't understand what these errors mean...
I understand some of them have to do with the way I'm using the `unique_ptr`, but since my IDE doesn't directly point out the incriminated lines I don't know what to do.

```
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:41,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Column.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _Args = {const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<Column, std::default_delete<Column> > >&}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >]':
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _Args = {const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<Column, std::default_delete<Column> > >&}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > > >]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:637:32:   required from 'void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_construct_node(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<Column, std::default_delete<Column> > >&}; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:506:3:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Reuse_or_alloc_node::operator()(_Arg&&) [with _Arg = const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >&; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:677:33:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_clone_node(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type, _NodeGen&) [with _NodeGen = std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > > >::_Reuse_or_alloc_node; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type = const std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:1834:13:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, _NodeGen&) [with _NodeGen = std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > > >::_Reuse_or_alloc_node; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type = const std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr = std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:891:15:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_copy(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, _NodeGen&) [with _NodeGen = std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > > >::_Reuse_or_alloc_node; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >*]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:1742:16:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Column> > >]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:100:11:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<Column>]'
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Column.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:292:17: note: 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<Column>]' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^~~~
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:292:17: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Column; _Dp = std::default_delete<Column>]'
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/locale:43,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iomanip:43,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Date.h:12,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\DateColumn.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.h:14,
                 from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:394:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\Final_Project_2nd.dir\build.make:179: CMakeFiles/Final_Project_2nd.dir/Tab.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/Final_Project_2nd.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/Final_Project_2nd.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: Final_Project_2nd] Error 2
```

This is `Tab.h`:

```
class Tab {
public:
    Tab();
    ~Tab();
    void addColumn(string name, string type);
    void addRecord(string column);
    void operator=(const Tab& to_assign);
private:
    map<string, unique_ptr<Column>> _columns;
    int _primary_key;
};
```

And these are two methods:

```
void Tab::addColumn(string name, string type) {
    // I switch all the different types and create a new element on the columns map
    // depending on what is the result
    switch(Type2Int(type)) {
        case OptionInt:
            _columns[name].reset(new IntColumn());
            break;
        case OptionFloat:
            _columns[name].reset(new FloatColumn());
            break;
        case OptionChar:
            _columns[name].reset(new CharColumn());
            break;
        case OptionText:
            _columns[name].reset(new TextColumn());
            break;
        case OptionTime:
            _columns[name].reset(new TimeColumn());
            break;
        case OptionDate:
            _columns[name].reset(new DateColumn());
            break;
    }
}
void Tab::operator=(const Tab &to_assign) {
    _columns = to_assign._columns;
}
```

`ColumnImpl` class:

```
template <typename T> class ColumnImpl : public Column {
public:
    ColumnImpl();
    ColumnImpl(const T& to_set);
    vector<T> const& getData() const { return _data; }
    void addElem(const T& elem_to_add);
    void operator=(const ColumnImpl& to_assign);
protected:
    vector<T> _data;
};
```

And this is a supsect method:

```
template<typename T>
void ColumnImpl<T>::operator=(const ColumnImpl &to_assign) {
    _data = to_assign._data;
}
```

`Database.h`:

```
class Database {
public:
    Database();
    ~Database();
    void createNewTable(string name);
    void addColumnToTab(string tab_name, string col_name, string type);
private:
    map<string, Tab> _tables;
};
```

These are the only two methods I've implemented:

```
void Database::createNewTable(string name) {
    _tables[name] = Tab();
}
void Database::addColumnToTab(string tab_name, string col_name, string type) {
    const auto & it_target_tab = _tables.find(tab_name);
    it_target_tab->second.addColumn(col_name, type);
}
```

Comment: `from C:\Users\Andrea\CLionProjects\Final_Project_2nd\Tab.cpp:5:` -- What is at line 5 of `Tab.cpp`?  Second, it would be better if you posted your code instead of these errors.

Comment: Looks like at least the first error is that you're trying to create a constexpr pair with a type that can't be constexpr. Second it looks like you're trying to copy a unique pointer. Move it into place instead.

Comment: We can help you with some of those errors, but we need to see the code that produced them to explain why they happened and recommend solutions that have more applicability to you than, "Don't do that."

Comment: Ok, I can also upload it all, but it's a lot of code... I have a class `Tab.h`, a class `Database.h`, a base class `Column.h`, a template `ColumnImpl.h` and many inherited classes `IntColumn.h`, `FloatColumn`, `CharColumn.h`, etc. 

Do I have to upload everything? (If yes here in the comment section or in the text of the question?)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie line 5 is: `#include "Tab.h"`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to copy construct a unique_ptr ... line 12 of Date.h maybe? You need to provide the MINIMAL code needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Make a [mre]. I'm sure that you realize most of your code isn't relevant to the problem, so just remove it. Also please [edit] important information into the question.

Comment: Error messages can be pretty daunting until you learn how to read them. The stuff you posted has only **two** error messages. They're just longwinded. The first is the one that says "error": after mentioning "new_allocator.h:136:4". That one is followed by a "note:" that gives you more information. Then there's the second error, in one of the lines that mentions "stl_pair.h:292:17". It, too, is followed by a "note:" that tells you more about it. Ignore the second error; it may or may not mean anything. Fix the first one. If the second one goes away, you don't need to fix it. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you Pete, at least now it's clearer to me which is the problem, but I still cannot figure out which lines are wrong and what I did...

Comment: Your copy assignment is invalid for Tab. You can't copy unique_ptr, which is contained in your `_columns` map

Comment: @ChrisMM Should I use shared_ptr instead?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve, but that could work.

Comment: @ChrisMM I think it worked, all the errors vanished except for this one:

`C:/Users/Andrea/CLionProjects/Final_Project_2nd/Tab.cpp:16: undefined reference to IntColumn::IntColumn()'`

And it's saying the same for every single inherited class and `~Tab()`...

Comment: @ChrisMM My goal is, as you could guess from the code above, to create a table made of `Column`s being able to add a Record working on the `_data` vectors and then putting all the `Tab`les in a `Database`